# AWS WordPress with EFS

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-efs

I building an AutoScaling WordPress Enviroment but have a question on EFS while setting up a CF Template. Am I suppose to mount the EFS on top of the existing WP Directory i.e /var/www/html or copy the WordPress Files to the EFS and then mount it to /var/www/html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So WordPress backed by EFS.

Firstly you will create the EFS, then mounting is done. After that one cron job will be written to copy all the Wordpress files from var/www/html to mounted directory.

**creating EFS**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption:
    EFSVolumeName: "EFS_Wordpress"
    VPCId: "vpc-xxxx"
## Subnet Options
    SubnetA: "subnet-xxxx"
    SubnetB: "subnet-xxxx"
    SubnetC: "subnet-xxxx"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    FILE_SYSTEM_ID: '`{"Ref" : "FileSystem"}`'
    MOUNT_DIRECTORY: '/wpfiles'
    REGION: '`{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}`'
Resources:
## Mount Target Resources
  MountTargetA:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: {Ref: FileSystem}
      SecurityGroups:
      - {Ref: MountTargetSecurityGroup}
      SubnetId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: SubnetA}
  MountTargetB:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: {Ref: FileSystem}
      SecurityGroups:
      - {Ref: MountTargetSecurityGroup}
      SubnetId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: SubnetB}
  MountTargetC:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: {Ref: FileSystem}
      SecurityGroups:
      - {Ref: MountTargetSecurityGroup}
      SubnetId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: SubnetC}

##############################################
#### Do not modify values below this line ####
##############################################

  FileSystem:
    Type: AWS::EFS::FileSystem
    Properties:
      FileSystemTags:
      - Key: Name
        Value:
          Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: EFSVolumeName, DefaultValue: "EFS_Wordpress"}

  MountTargetSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for mount target
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - FromPort: '2049'
        IpProtocol: tcp
        SourceSecurityGroupId:
          Fn::GetAtt: [AWSEBSecurityGroup, GroupId]
        ToPort: '2049'
      VpcId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: VPCId}
```

**mounting EFS**

```
container_commands:
  1chown:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /wpfiles"
  2create:
    command: "sudo -u webapp mkdir -p wp-content/uploads"
  3link:
    command: "sudo -u webapp ln -s /wpfiles wp-content/uploads"
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    FILE_SYSTEM_ID: '`{"Ref" : "FileSystem"}`'
    MOUNT_DIRECTORY: '/wpfiles'
    REGION: '`{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}`'

packages:
  yum:
    nfs-utils: []
    jq: []

commands:
  01_mount:
    command: "/tmp/mount-efs.sh"

files:
  "/tmp/mount-efs.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      content : |
        #!/bin/bash

        EFS_REGION=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.REGION')
        EFS_MOUNT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.MOUNT_DIRECTORY')
        EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.FILE_SYSTEM_ID')

        echo "Mounting EFS filesystem ${EFS_DNS_NAME} to directory ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} ..."

        echo 'Stopping NFS ID Mapper...'
        service rpcidmapd status &> /dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            echo 'rpc.idmapd is already stopped!'
        else
            service rpcidmapd stop
            if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
                echo 'ERROR: Failed to stop NFS ID Mapper!'
                exit 1
            fi
        fi

        echo 'Checking if EFS mount directory exists...'
        if [ ! -d ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} ]; then
            echo "Creating directory ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} ..."
            mkdir -p ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo 'ERROR: Directory creation failed!'
                exit 1
            fi
        else
            echo "Directory ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} already exists!"
        fi

        mountpoint -q ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 ${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID}.efs.${EFS_REGION}.amazonaws.com:/ ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}"
            mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 ${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID}.efs.${EFS_REGION}.amazonaws.com:/ ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
            if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
                echo 'ERROR: Mount command failed!'
                exit 1
            fi
            chmod 777 ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
            runuser -l  ec2-user -c "touch ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}/it_works"
            if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
                echo 'ERROR: Permission Error!'
                exit 1
            else
                runuser -l  ec2-user -c "rm -f ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}/it_works"
            fi
        else
            echo "Directory ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} is already a valid mountpoint!"
        fi

        echo 'EFS mount complete.'
```

**Copying files to Mount Directory**

```
files:
  "/tmp/wpcopysymlink.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      content : |
        #!/bin/bash

        ## ebextensions check if Symlink and wp is already installed if not copy it to EFS

        echo "Time: $(date). Checking to see Wordpress is already in EFS or not..."
        if [ ! -d /wpfiles/wp-admin ]; then
            echo "Wordpress isn't installed I'm going to copy the base install to the EFS Shared directory /wpfiles ..."
            cp -r /var/app/current/* /wpfiles
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo 'ERROR: Directory Copy failed!'
                exit 1
            fi
        else
            echo "Wordpress is already there /wpfiles/wp-admin already exists!"
        fi

        echo 'Checking to see if the symlink is there from the app dir to EFS or not...'

        if [ -L /var/app/current ] ; then
        echo "Good link so your good to go"
            else
                echo "No link so I'm removing the directory and creating the symlink in it's place to EFS"
                rm -rf /var/app/current
                ln -s /wpfiles /var/app/current
        fi

        echo "Time: $(date). All done for EFS"
```

Now you can write a cron job which will run after every 5min to copy all the files to mount directory.

**For ref**:- https://github.com/karan6190/WordpressAutoScalable-EFS